# 1 blue bar, but Google search results don't load

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, browser, networking, bugs

I typed something into the address bar of the builtin browser, Android Browser 4, and it tried to load Google but the browser said, "There was a network error."

**Does anyone know why Google searches sometimes don't load?**

Also, another time, I was trying to load accounts.google.com and it wouldn't load but other websites and parts of the Google website worked just fine.

Sometimes the WiFi icon has a dark grey/black triangle or two on it. I don't know what the triangles mean.

WiFi info:
xfinitywifi

- 1 blue bar of WiFi
- Status: Connected
- Signal strength: Fair
- Link speed: 1 Mbps
  (but if he wears the speed boots he can run twice as fast)
- Security: None
- IP address: [redacted]

Versions:

- SE App Version: 1.0.85
- Browser version: 4.1.2-eng.tyrone.20121202.215512
- Device Manufacturer: Malata
- Device Model: Malata SMBA1002
- ViewSonic gTablet UPC300-2.2
- OS Version: 4.1.2 (eng.G_Harmony.20121202.215512)